# Timeout error in VB.NET while running a sql script

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Can someone please help?  I am trying to create a grid view in visual studio by connecting to a server and using a stored procedure.  I am getting a time out error when I test it out.  Can someone advise me as to what I can do?  The query itself takes about 7 minutes to complete.  The data is stored in a table.  What can I do to extend the timeout?

Here is my connection script:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>SQL-EDD 4 SERVER</title>
</head>
<body>
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      runat="server">
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DBNAME" HeaderText="DBNAME" SortExpression="DBNAME" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IMGS" HeaderText="IMGS" ReadOnly="True" 
              SortExpression="IMGS" />
          <asp:BoundField DataField="IMG_DATE_UPLOAD" HeaderText="IMG_DATE_UPLOAD" 
              ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="IMG_DATE_UPLOAD" />
      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" SelectCommand="IMGCTR"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JEFFREYEDD4 %>" 
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" />


    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

THE SQL CODE IS BELOW:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @DBNAME NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DBNAME1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @varSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

DROP TABLE TEMPIMGCOUNTERSERVER3 
CREATE TABLE TEMPIMGCOUNTERSERVER3 
(DBNAME NVARCHAR(MAX),
IMG_DATE_UPLOAD DATETIME,
IMG_UPLOAD_COUNT INT)

DECLARE DBNAME CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT [NAME] FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] like 'z%' and [name] not like 'Z1301_TEVA_SINGLE' AND [NAME] NOT LIKE 'Z1016_E-100016R'
AND CREATE_DATE BETWEEN GETDATE()-30 AND GETDATE()
ORDER BY [Name]

OPEN DBNAME

FETCH NEXT FROM DBNAME INTO @DBname
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
BEGIN

SET @DBNAME1=('USE ['+ @DBNAME +']')
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  @DBNAME1

    Set @varSQL='INSERT INTO TEMPIMGCOUNTERSERVER3 (DBNAME, IMG_UPLOAD_COUNT, IMG_DATE_UPLOAD) 
    SELECT ''['+@DBNAME+']'' AS DBNAME, SUM(PGCOUNT) AS IMAGES, convert(NVARCHAR(10), CREATED, 101) AS CREATED
        FROM ['+@DBNAME+'].dbo.tbldoc WHERE CREATED BETWEEN ''2011-01-16'' AND ''2011-01-22'' AND PGCOUNT >0 GROUP BY CREATED 
        HAVING SUM(PGCOUNT) IS NOT NULL'    
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @varSQL

    FETCH NEXT FROM DBNAME 
    INTO @DBNAME
    END

    CLOSE DBNAME
    DEALLOCATE DBNAME

    INSERT TEMPIMGCOUNTERSERVER3 (DBNAME, IMG_UPLOAD_COUNT)  
    SELECT 'TOTAL_IMGSIZE_IN_MBS', SUM(IMG_UPLOAD_COUNT) FROM TEMPIMGCOUNTERSERVER3 

    SELECT  DBNAME, SUM(IMG_UPLOAD_COUNT) AS IMGS, convert(NVARCHAR(10), IMG_DATE_UPLOAD, 101) AS IMG_DATE_UPLOAD FROM TEMPIMGCOUNTERSERVER3 where IMG_UPLOAD_COUNT > 0
    GROUP BY DBNAME, IMG_DATE_UPLOAD
    ORDER BY IMG_DATE_UPLOAD
```

Error is as follows:

### Server Error in '/lawsqlreporting' Application.

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +1951450
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4849003
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2394
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +33
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +83
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +297
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +954
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +32
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +141
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +12
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +130
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +287
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +92
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +1297
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +142
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +73
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +82
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +72
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +87
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +44
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +171
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.4952; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4955

Comment: Is this an asp.net timeout or sql command or connection timeout?

Comment: You could increase the time out period your app will allow, but you are better off trying to tune the stored procedure to return the results faster.  Can you post the SQL code?

Comment: Continuing with Oded, please post the full error message you get.

Comment: I just learned about this hidden proc today, on Stackoverflow, no less: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Sp_MSforeachDB. That will remove some of the overhead in your query.

Comment: I tried that before.  The problem is I only I need to query databases beginning with 'Z' that were created during a 60 day time period.

Comment: Jeff - I suspect you may want to take the sql query by itself and repost it as a seperate question relating to how to tune it with some details as to what information you are trying to get.  Is this audit information about the dbs themselves?  If so alot of that may be in the sys databases.  I would also look at utilizing #temp tables instead of a cursor..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to increase the timeout you can increase the CommandTimeout for the DataCommand that's fetching the data. When you use SqlDataSource this is done using an event handler to obtain the command.
Insert the following in code behind of your page:

```
Private Sub SqlDataSource1_Selecting(sender as object, _
   e as SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) handles SqlDataSource1.Selecting

   e.Command.CommandTimeout = 500 
End Sub
```

In order to increase the web application's request timeout you have to set the executionTimeout to a suitable length by modifying the web config.

```
<httpRuntime
   executionTimeout = "600" 
/>
```

But better is of course to tune your query.

Comment: @jeff - Sorry! Forgot to clean up the last remnants of C#. Should of course be End Sub instead

Answer (score 4):

First of all - extending the timeout is not the solution. Nevertheless, here's how you do it with your data source:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender,
SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
e.Command.CommandTimeout = 30;
}
```

Here's the analysis you should perform:

First: does the stored procedure execute satisfactorily when executed outside of the context of the page, e.g., in the query window? If not, the problem is with the query. Google "optimize sql query" and you'll get a bunch of good stuff.

If it does, then how do other queries in the application perform (assuming this is not the first one you're trying to get working)? If they work fine, double-check that you're using the same connection string.

Comment: @Chris the command timeout is in seconds which is defaulted to 30 seconds. It should probably be > 480

Comment: Yeah, he can set it to whatever - but he shouldn't.

Comment: I agree, more than likely extending the timeout is not the solution. There are myriad ways to tune your SQL code, and my guess is with an SP that runs for 7 minutes...you really need to tune it. In addition to tuning your SQL code, think about how much data you are bringing back to the ASP.net page as well. Do you need all that data? Try to approach the problem from the angle of simplicity.

Comment: Last suggestion - set up a Sql Agent job that executes this query twice an hour (or however often) and caches the results in a table. Then just query that table - results will come back nigh instantly.

Comment: It would go in the codebehind file : default2.aspx.vb. You'll also have to convert it to VB - the above example is in C#.

Comment: @Jeff - see my answer for the vb.net equivalent

Answer (score 0):

So here is an approach you might want to take a look at with out the cursor.  I have not run this but with some tweaking it should work.

```
CREATE Table #TableNames (DBNameID INT Not NUll Identity, DBName VarCHAR(50))

CREATE TABLE #TableResults (DBNAME NVARCHAR(MAX),  IMG_DATE_UPLOAD DATETIME,  IMG_UPLOAD_COUNT INT)

Insert Into #TableNames(DBName)
SELECT [NAME] FROM sys.databases 
WHERE [name] like 'z%' and [name] not like 'Z1301_TEVA_SINGLE' 
AND [NAME] NOT LIKE 'Z1016_E-100016R' 
AND CREATE_DATE BETWEEN GETDATE()-30 AND GETDATE() ORDER BY [Name]

DECLARE @Counter INT = 1;
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @varSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
Declare @rows INT;
select @rows = COUNT(DBNameID) from #TableNames


While @Counter <= @rows BEGIN
    SET @DBName = (SELECT DBName from #TableNames where DBNameID = @Counter)

    Set @varSQL='INSERT INTO #TableResults (DBNAME, IMG_UPLOAD_COUNT, IMG_DATE_UPLOAD)      
SELECT ''['+@DBNAME+']'' AS DBNAME, SUM(PGCOUNT) AS IMAGES, convert(NVARCHAR(10), CREATED, 101) AS CREATED
FROM ['+@DBNAME+'].dbo.tbldoc WHERE CREATED BETWEEN ''2011-01-16'' AND ''2011-01-22'' AND PGCOUNT >0 GROUP BY CREATED          
HAVING SUM(PGCOUNT) IS NOT NULL' 

SET @Counter += 1
END

INSERT #TableResults (DBNAME, IMG_UPLOAD_COUNT)       
SELECT 'TOTAL_IMGSIZE_IN_MBS', SUM(IMG_UPLOAD_COUNT) 
FROM #TableResults       

SELECT  DBNAME, SUM(IMG_UPLOAD_COUNT) AS IMGS, convert(NVARCHAR(10), IMG_DATE_UPLOAD, 101) AS IMG_DATE_UPLOAD 
FROM #TableResults where IMG_UPLOAD_COUNT > 0     
GROUP BY DBNAME, IMG_DATE_UPLOAD     
ORDER BY IMG_DATE_UPLOAD

DROP TABLE #TableNames
DROP TABLE #TableResults
```

If you get this working at it still is taking too long you may want to look at how long it takes to run the select you are executing per db.  If each of these is taking a long time you may need to look at the query plan for that part of the query itself.